# Custom Sort Stringlist

Tags: string, delphi-7

I am an intermediate Delphi programmer that needs to learn a lot so I hope my question here is not to dumb. I have a file with 1546 strings that I need to place in a StringList and do a custom sort. The strings look like this:

```
2:X,X,2,2,2,X<A>11
7:5,7,7,6,5,5<A>08
3:3,X,0,0,1,0<C/D>11
5:X,2,4,2,5,2<Asus2/Gb>02
3:0,3,2,0,3,0<C/D>02
4:X,0,4,4,0,0<Asus2/Gb>11
4:X,X,4,4,4,2<B>01
3:3,2,1,0,0,3<B#5>11
```

I need them to look like this:

```
2:X,X,2,2,2,X<A>11
7:5,7,7,6,5,5<A>08
5:X,2,4,2,5,2<Asus2/Gb>11
4:X,0,4,4,0,0<Asus2/Gb>02
4:X,X,4,4,4,2<B>01
3:3,2,1,0,0,3<B#5>11
3:3,X,0,0,1,0<C/D>11
3:0,3,2,0,3,0<C/D>02
```

They need to be sorted by the portion of the string between the <...> and the last 2 chars. Any help would be much appreciated.

OK...done, Works quite well. Sorts a list with over 1500 strings in 62ms. Constructive criticism will be **appreciated**.

```
function SortChords(List:TStringList; idx1,idx2:integer): integer;
var
s1,s2:string;
begin
    s1:=List[idx1];
    s1:=copy(s1,pos('<',s1)+1,pos('>',s1)-pos('<',s1)-1);
    s2:=List[idx2];
    s2:=copy(s2,pos('<',s2)+1,pos('>',s2)-pos('<',s2)-1);
    if s1 < s2 then
    result:=-1
    else if s1 > s2 then
    result:=1
    else
    result:=0;
end;
```

Comment: Can you explain why your desired output puts the first two lines in the order it does (which appears to be by <A> and then 2, 7), but lines 3 and 4 sort as <Asus2/Gb> 5, 4)? What determines which <A> comes before the other, or which <Asus2/GB> is first? (And for that matter, what determines the order of the <C/D> entries?)

Comment: Parse the string into the keys that you need. Define a compare function based on those keys. Sort the list. What is stopping you?

Comment: You should also make an effort to solve this yourself. See TStringList.CustomSort in the documentation.

Comment: You would not be interested in a solution via sed and sort, would you?

Comment: I am working on a function and will post when done. Thanks for kicking me in the butt. Got me going.

Comment: Ken...The only importance is the that <A> is followed by <A#> then <A#+> and on down the line. So each of the strings is listed in alphabetical order according to just the chars between the <....>.  The other parts of the string mean nothing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write your own custom sort procedure and use TStringList.CustomSort to sort in the desired order.

The following demonstrates using the custom sort. It does not produce the exact output you describe, because you're not clear how you determine the precedence of two items that have the same value between the <> (as in lines 1 and 2, or 3 and 4, of your expected output; you can add code to decide the final order where I've indicated in the code comment. The sample is a complete console application that demonstrates sorting the values you've provided. It's slightly verbose in variable declarations for clarity.

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, Classes;

function ListSortProc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  StartPosA, EndPosA: Integer;
  StartPosB, EndPosB: Integer;
  TestValA, TestValB: string;
  Comp: Integer;
begin
  StartPosA := Pos('<', List[Index1]) + 1;
  EndPosA := Pos('>', List[Index1]);
  TestValA := Copy(List[Index1], StartPosA, EndPosA - StartPosA);
  StartPosB := Pos('<', List[Index2]) + 1;
  EndPosB := Pos('>', List[Index2]);
  TestValB := Copy(List[Index2], StartPosB, EndPosB - StartPosB);
  Result := CompareStr(TestValA, TestValB);
  { To do further processing for lines with the same value, add
    code here.

   if Result = 0 then
     // Decide on the order of the equal values with whatever
     // criteria you want.
  }
end;

var
  SL: TStringList;
  s: String;

begin
  SL := TStringList.Create;
  try
    SL.Add('2:X,X,2,2,2,X<A>11');
    SL.Add('7:5,7,7,6,5,5<A>08');
    SL.Add('3:3,X,0,0,1,0<C/D>11');
    SL.Add('5:X,2,4,2,5,2<Asus2/Gb>02');
    SL.Add('3:0,3,2,0,3,0<C/D>02');
    SL.Add('4:X,0,4,4,0,0<Asus2/Gb>11');
    SL.Add('4:X,X,4,4,4,2<B>01');
    SL.Add('3:3,2,1,0,0,3<B#5>11');
    SL.CustomSort(ListSortProc);
    for s in SL do
      WriteLn(s);
    ReadLn;
  finally
    SL.Free;
  end;
end.
```

The code above produces this output:

```
7:5,7,7,6,5,5<A>08
2:X,X,2,2,2,X<A>11
4:X,0,4,4,0,0<Asus2/Gb>11
5:X,2,4,2,5,2<Asus2/Gb>02
4:X,X,4,4,4,2<B>01
3:3,2,1,0,0,3<B#5>11
3:0,3,2,0,3,0<C/D>02
3:3,X,0,0,1,0<C/D>11
```